# Logic Apps data store at rest and in transit

Tags: azure-storage, azure-logic-apps

According to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-securing-a-logic-app) article Logic Apps relies on Azure Storage to store and automatically encrypt data at **rest**.
And
"During a logic app run, all the data is encrypted during **transit** by using Transport Layer Security (TLS) and at rest"

I have a Logic App that uses the Salesforce trigger and reads users info from SF, then does a bunch of things including using Graph API and creating Guests in AAD.

My question is if the Salesforce data is actually stored in Azure Storage? Based on the [history retention](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-limits-and-config#run-duration-and-retention-history-limits) I would think yes (90 days) as long as by "history in storage" here is meant Azure Storage

Answer (score 1):

I think you are right, from the doc, the Salesforce data should be stored in Azure Storage.